# Error Code:2 Unexpected Top-level Exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in android development and when importing project in androidstudio
Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
E:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --
output E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-  user\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define      Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

inputList.txt File :

```
E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android- user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-20.0.0- 22f67c0dddc9c688e0794d450b815b28f58e1d83.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-20.0.0-70abc57678073852a9e6f7ebae30976bb22ec41d.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\universal-image-loader-1.9.1-b9c11698ebf40b256b359f271d0bd7e3629612d8.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\xstream-1.4.7-816d435be49dd5bc1f491c17effc3dddbc49ba4a.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\libGoogleAnalyticsServices-e2a7597e511aa28da2b973eefa67e920097e0deb.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\google-play-services-ee4019f3cee39571bf6dc0f712c4b22b32b6cae3.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-7ec2c6eefdabe7608a38cfb42d3fa0ec0fa556d2.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-99d7a950ad16ef4b71207dd3f54ad9df9c933c00.jar
 E:\android\CFPEvents\Gradleprojectcfp-android-user\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-6090079305bc6decaac8787edd923af44cc8510d.jar
```

build.gradle File :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.7.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
 }
```

Googleplayserices is added in android manifest file

android:minSdkversion="14"
android:targetSDKversion="19"

Please help me

Comment: remove `compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')` from your build.gradle and also remove the jar from your libs directory after that sync your project with gradle.

Comment: I included it in answer to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens if you have multiple instance of same library as dependency in your project. Specific to you is the Google play Services

remove

`compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')`

from your build.gradle and also remove the jar from your libs directory because you are including all jars in lib directory to your dependency by writing very first line in dependencies closure.
 After doing all sync your project with gradle.